# JPA select master and filter details by the master's property

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I need to figure out how to select master with filtered details depending on the master's property.
The method: getMasters(userId: Long, page: Pageable)

The requirement for each Master in result list is that:

- if the userId equals to master.userId, select only the newest detail with the master (by created) regardless the state
- if the userId != master.userId and APPROVED detail exists, select only the APPROVED detail with the master
- if the userId !=master.userId and APPROVED detail does not exist, filter the Master record entirely.

**Could you please help me how to achieve this with criteria query, JPQL or native query?**

This will be very frequent query with pagination so I'd like to make it as efficient as possible.

I have JPA mapping this way:

```
@Entity
class Master {
    @Id var pk: Long? = null,
    var userId: Long,
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="master", fetch=FetchType.LAZY var details: MutableList<Detail> = mutableListOf()
}

@Entity
class Detail {
    @Id var pk: Long? = null,
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) var state: State,
    var created: Instant
}

enum class State { DRAFT, APPROVED }
```

Q1: how to achieve this by criteria query/JPQL or native query?

Q2: is it possible with JPA to return Master filled only with one detail instead of full bag? Maybe with detached entity? At the end, Master is just simple POJO

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
this is the sql I use, but still not there with the criteria builder..

```
WITH my_masters AS (SELECT r.pk
                    FROM master r
                    WHERE r.user_id = 'tester1'),
     visible_details AS (SELECT v.*
                          FROM detail v
                                   INNER JOIN master r ON v.master_pk = r.pk
                          WHERE (v.master_pk IN (SELECT * FROM my_masters) OR v.state = 'PUBLISHED')),
     latest_detail_pks AS (select v2.master_pk,
                                   max(v2.created) as created
                            from visible_details v2
                            group by v2.master_pk)
select v.*
from visible_details v
         INNER JOIN latest_detail_pks l
                    ON v.master_pk = l.master_pk
                        and v.created = l.created
order by v.created DESC;
```